# Use a React component inside another component that needs childrens

Tags: reactjs

Sorry the title is surely not clear.

I've a component that take in paramater an array of children. I want to abstract this array of children into it's own component. However extracting it to another component make it like it was a single child.

Here is what I want to do (really easy example):

```
const AllMyChildrens = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, index) => (
    <div key={index}>{index}</div>
  ));
};

const MyContainer = ({ children }: any) => {
  return (
    <div>
      // error children.map is undefined
      {children.map((child, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{child}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const MyApp = () => {
  return (
    <MyContainer>
      <AllMyChildrens /> // error ReactNode[] needed
    </MyContainer>
  );
};
```

EDIT: I created a function instead, it works, but I'm wondering if we can do it with a component.

Comment: you want to iterate children?

Comment: The problem is that, `AllMyChildrens` is not a component. you are returning an Array of `JSX.Element` or React Node. You can't use it as a component.

Comment: You can make your `AllMyChildrens` component return a fragment containing your children `<>{Array.from(...)}</>`